# Вложенные циклы (while)

Tags: java

Как написать программу, чтобы она выдавала результат в консоль следующее треугольником

> 1 2 3 4 5
>
> 1 2 3 4
>
> 1 2 3
>
> 1 2
>
> 1

У меня с этого дальше ничего не получается

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int n = 9;
        int i = n, j = n;
        while (j > 1){
            while (i > j){
                i--;
                }
            j--;
            System.out.println(" " + i + " " + j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И вариант через while =)

```
public class Test 
{ 
    public static void main(String [] args)
    { 
        int n = 9; 
        int i = n, j = 1; 
        while (i >= 1)
        { 
            while (j <= i)
            { 
                System.out.print(" " + j);
                j++;
            } 
            System.out.println("");
            j = 1;
            i--;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int j = 5;
for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int o = j; o > 0; o--) {
        System.out.print(o + " ");//Печатаем строку
    }
    System.out.println();//Переводим каретку, чтобы следующий цикл был с новой строки
    j--;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю нужно так, хотя с Java на знаком

```
 public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int n = 9;
          int i = n, j = n;
          while (j > 1){
            while (i > j){
               i--;
               System.out.print(i + " " );
            }
        j--;
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Немного не то, так как на каждом шаге внешнего цикла внутренний будет выполнятся только один раз

Comment: Ага, увидел, в чем у меня ошибка, да и перевод строки не добавил.

Но я с JAVA вообще не работал и не работаю, просто по аналогии с паскалем писал.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю Вам рассмотреть мой программный код, который полностью удовлетворяет условию задачи и выводит в том виде, в котором Вам нужно.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 9;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n - i + 1; j++) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Надеюсь, Вам подойдет данный класс.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ @Евгений Серебров